# How can I hide all the rows whose first cell contents is “aaa” using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I hide all the rows of a table(MyTable) whose first cell contents is “aaa” when the checkbox(MyCheckbox) is checked and show the rows when the checkbox(MyCheckbox) is unchecked using Jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am going to change my question a little bit. I have 4 checkboxes with IDS('aaa', 'bbb','ccc','ddd') and I have table whose rows first td has either got value 'aaa' or 'bbb' or ccc' or 'ddd'). If I check the checkbox with id('aaa') it should hide rows with values 'aaa' and If I uncheck then it should show rows with 'aaa'. When I check the checkbox with id('bbb') it should hide rows with values 'bbb' and If I uncheck then it should show rows with 'bbb' values.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
    $('#table tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('td:first-child').html() === 'aaa') {
            if ($('#checkbox:checked').val() === 'on')
                $(this).hide();
            else
                $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick. It binds a click handler to "MyCheckbox" that fires when clicked. If the box is checked it goes over each of the td's in the table and checks the text. If the text is "aaa" it hides it.

```
$("#MyCheckbox").click(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $("tr td:first-child","#myTable").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() == "aaa"){
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("tr td:first-child","#myTable").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() == "aaa"){
        $(this).closest("tr").show();
      }
    });  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do: http://jsfiddle.net/ABbCf/

```
$('#chk').click(function() {
    var table = $('#MyTable');
    var trs = $('#MyTable tr');
    trs.each(function() {
        if($(this).children().eq(0).text() === "aaa") {
            if($('#chk').attr("checked")) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkbox').click(function()
{
     var filter = this.value;
     if(this.checked)
     {
          $('table').find("td:contains(" + filter + ")").parent().hide();
     }else
     {
          $('table').find("td:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().show();
     }
})
```

Comment: Note to speed this up a bit for IE you will want to start your find on something that has an id but element searches are (like what I have here) still faster than css class selection. Also you will want the click event based on your checkbox I didn't see that you had put "MyCheckbox" so I just used a class of "checkbox" for the search.

Comment: @Asif change this line: var filter = this.value; to this: var filter = this.id;

Comment: Then just remove the .parent() which targets the row. Though your question does ask to hide the rows....

Answer (score 0):

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/saQwh/1/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var theId = this.id;

    $("td").each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == theId) {
            $(this).parent().toggle();
        }        
    });
});
```